# Tic Tac Toe Board 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on a tic tac toe game. I wrote a code to print a board, it holds underscore brackets for empty spaces of a 2D array. Does anyone know a way I could not have the underscore bracts print for the last line? Xs and Os are stored as Strings "*X*" and "*O*" Thanks!

```
public void PrintBoard()
{

  System.out.println();
  for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
     {
        if (board[i][j] == null) 
           System.out.print("___");
        else
           System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        if (j < 2)
           System.out.print("|");
        else
           System.out.println();
     }
  }
  System.out.println();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding "if (i<2)" before your print of the underscores?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
     {
        if (board[i][j] == null) 
        {
           if (i < 2)
                System.out.print("___");
        }
        else
           System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        if (j < 2)
           System.out.print("|");
        else
           System.out.println();
     }
  }
  System.out.println();
```

Also, I don't like your using board.length for the inner loop; it should be board[i].length.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
```

Should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
```

Also, I'd probably change the loop a bit...

```
if (j != 0) {
  System.out.print("|");
}
if (board[i][j] == null) 
  System.out.print("___");
else
  System.out.print(board[i][j]);
```

And then add a println after that inner loop.